# Why is my basic recursion looping infinitely?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion, iteration

```
let data = [1, 2, 3]
let sorted = []

let push = function(i) {
  while(i<data.length) {
    sorted.push(data[i])
    push(i + 1)
  }
}

push(0)
```

Hey guys,

I am writing some basic recursion and it doesn't seem to exit. Sorry for the basic question but I was hoping somebody could explain it.

Expected behavior: imitates a for loop - iterates over array and pushes to new array. Exits when we reach `i == data.length`

Actual behavior: runs for 0, 1, 2, then 2 until stack overflow.

Codefiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/t579jbog/

Comment: Your `while` loop never changes the value of `i`

Comment: You should be using `if` instead of `while`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `if` not `while`, and make sure you use a different value of `i` in the recursive call.

```js
let data = [1, 2, 3]
let sorted = []

let push = function(i) {
  if (i < data.length) {
    sorted.push(data[i]);
    push(i + 1);
  }
}

push(0);

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: `i + 1` works just as well as `++i` there. modifying `i` is not necessary, as `i` is not used again in the function.

Comment: My bad @Paulpro, I'll add that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shift() intead of the index (shift() removes the first item on array and returns the value - which can be pushed into the sorted array.

Then simply check if the array length >0 and if it is - pass it to the same function to redo the function until the array is empty.

I am consoling the sorted array to demonstrate it is getting the values from each time around.

```js
let data = [1, 2, 3]
let sorted = []

let push = function(arr) {
    sorted.push(arr.shift())
    console.log(sorted);
    
    if(arr.length > 0) {
      push(arr); 
    }
  }


push(data);
```